# Difference in resulted order of records for same query

Tags: sql, database

I have this query:

```
SELECT -- some columns -- 
FROM ABC 
     INNER JOIN DEF ON DEF._VALUE = SUBSTRING(ABC._VALUE, 1, 6) 
     INNER JOIN GHI ON GHI.CODE = DEF.CODE 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN DC ON DC.PAN = ABC.PAN 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN BR ON BR.NAME = DC.NAME 
WHERE ABC.RECEIVED_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'2014-01-01 00:00:00',120) 
      AND ABC.RECEIVED_DATE <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'2014-01-10 23:59:59',120) 
      AND ('-1' IN ('-1') OR ABC.ID IN ('-1')) 
      AND ('-1' IN ('2012') OR BR.NAME IN ('2012')) 
      AND ABC.PAN LIKE '%' + '%' + '%' 
      AND DC.RL LIKE '%' + '%' + '%' 
      AND (ABC.RC = '1')
```

Every time it hits the DataBase it gets the SAME NUMBER (say 15) of records but the ORDER of the records IS DIFFERENT every time. Like if, in first attempt the record that was shown as record#-1 is shown record#-6 in second attempt may be. In otherwords, the order gets disturbed (order not consistent every time).

What could be the possible reasons? Because of Indexes or something? I do not no for sure why is it so. Guide me please

Comment: ok.. But when I just tried : SELECT * FROM ABC. It did'nt give me the records in random order any more, provided that i didnt use ORDER BY explicitly in this case either.

Comment: Read this: if you **NEED** ordering - you **MUST** specify an `ORDER BY` - as simple as that. No `ORDER BY` ---> **NO** (guaranteed) ordering

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not specifying an explicit `ORDER BY` clause, there is **no ordering** (this is the default behavior for any RDBMS).

The data is returned in whichever fashion the database engine feels like it. This *might look* ordered - but there's no guarantee - next time you run the query (without `ORDER BY`), your results returned *could be in a different order*.

If you need ordering - you **MUST** specify an `ORDER BY` clause!

See this blog post [Without ORDER BY, there is no default sort order](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx) by Alexander Kuznetsov which contains a nice simple repro script that demonstrates this fact - no `ORDER BY` == no default ordering ....

Comment: Try for yourself: [Example 1](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Expecting%20order%20without%20ORDER%20BY%20(1).sql), [Example 2](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Expecting%20order%20without%20ORDER%20BY%20(2).sql), [Example 3](http://gvee.co.uk/files/sql/Expecting%20order%20without%20ORDER%20BY%20(3).sql)

Comment: @gvee: thanks - but what is this supposed to prove? Have you looked at the sample by Alex Kuznetsov I linked to??

Comment: Hi @marc_s, yes, I have seen Alex' example before. These are simply smaller examples of why you can't expect order without specifying `ORDER BY`. P.S. the comment was not aimed at you, but at future readers.